# i like to add the AOSP 4.3 to a gerrit project

Tags: git, gerrit, repository

"i am pretty new to this stuff so kindly bear with me"

i have downloaded AOSP4.2.1 to my ~/Android_setup/AOSP4.2.1 using below steps and was able to compile and build the images.

<< repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2.1_r1
repo sync >>

and now want to setup a Gerrit server on my PC, and create a new project with the AOSP code, i was able to setup a local gerrit server in my ~/gerrit_example folder. i was able to create new proejct in gerrit using the UI which has created a folder  ~/home/gerrit_example/git/AOSP4.2.1.git.i can see the project from the web interface as 
http:// localhost:8081 /# /admin/projects/AOSP4.2.1

Now i want to merge/redirect this AOSP4.2.1 code in ~/Android_Setup/AOSP4.2.1 to the gerrit project

Please let me know how to setup

Answer (score 4):

The AOSP 4.3 codebase is not one single repository, it is a collection of lots of repositories.  See the full list at https://android.googlesource.com/.

Fortunately it is easy to get these set up in your Gerrit server.  You don't need to create a project for each one through the web UI, you just need to clone the repositories to your `git/` folder.  So as your gerrit user, in the `~/home/gerrit_example/git/` folder, run these commands:

`repo init --mirror -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`

`repo sync`

Restart Gerrit, and it will see the new repositories and create projects for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot brad, since i already have the AOSP4.3 downloaded into a different folder,  could i just copy the whole stuff into git folder of my gerrit ~/home/gerrit_example/git/, also in my AOSP4.2.1 folder i have downloaded, i only see .repo and do not see .git, do i need to initialize git or run any commands?

Comment: Nope, copying the AOSP4.3 you downloaded won't work.  You need just the .git directories, which is what the `--mirror` option does in `repo sync`.  Also the folder layout will be a bit different.

Comment: Great thanks brad, Now that i have the projects populated into my gerrit, i would like to make a repo for the team to download, could you please help on steps how to create a repo for these list of git folders , thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That sounds like a different issue.  If this problem is solved, please accept the solution and post a new question.  We will get you set up :)

Comment: Sandeep, has this issue been solved?  If so please accept this answer as correct so others will benefit and we can move on to fixing your next problem.

Comment: So I noticed that when I ran the "init" sequence with Gerrit, the directories `All-Projects.git/` and `All-Users.git/` were created -- those won't get in the way?

Comment: Nope, Gerrit uses these internally, they are safe to ignore.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Next question: Is there something I should do to the downloaded repo so Gerrit users can edit it? `repo upload .` is failing with `error.GitError: remote aosp has no review url`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073237