# How to Make a local repo for a list of git projects of AOSP ,

Tags: git, installation, gerrit, repository

How do i make a repo setup for the AOSP code which is populated into gerrit, this is a follow up question to my post below which is sovled with brad, Huge thanks to him for the support.

[i like to add the AOSP 4.3 to a gerrit project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922653/i-like-to-add-the-aosp-4-3-to-a-gerrit-project)

Now that i have mirror setup for all the git projects in my gerrit, i would like to setup a local repo for my team to download, could you please help me the steps to be followed to get this done

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the projects are already set up in gerrit your users can already clone them.

To download the whole android project, they need to use repo:

```
$ repo init -u git://path/to/gerrit/platform/manifest -b master
$ repo sync
```

For this to work you need to have set up a mirror of the platform/manifest project on your gerrit server, and edited its default.xml file to point out your gerrit server as the default remote.

Comment: Thanks david, great help